# How to adjust x-axis in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a plot of depth of fish individuals over time. The background represents the temperature, the grey dots is the raw depth data, and the black line is the geom_smooth line of raw data (image of plot is attached here). I used ggplot to make the graphs, but my x-axis (= date/time) is slightly moved to the right. I need the axis to be adjusted in the middle (standardized). This is my very long code for the plot:

```
tibble(y=c(-7:0)) %>% 
  expand_grid(TBRtemperature %>% select(`Date and Time (UTC)`, Temperature)) %>% 
  rename(dt="Date and Time (UTC)") %>% 
  filter(yday(dt)>136&yday(dt)<147) %>% 
  mutate(dt=with_tz(dt, "Europe/Oslo")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(dt, y, fill=Temperature)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("lightblue", "white", "red")) +
  scale_x_datetime(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  geom_point(data=fbd_TBR %>% filter(yday(dt)>136&yday(dt)<147, n()>100), aes(dt, -Data/10, group=paste0(ID, Trial)), colour="grey50", alpha=0.2) +
  geom_smooth(data=fbd_TBR %>% filter(yday(dt)>136&yday(dt)<147, n()>100), aes(dt, -Data/10, group=paste0(ID, Trial), colour=paste0(ID, sep=" - ", Weight)), colour="black") +
  labs(y="Depth (m)", x=("Time (days)"), title = "Trial 2") +
  facet_wrap(~paste(ID, sep = " - ", Weight)) + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold"), strip.text = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

Anyone who knows how the axis can be adjusted?

[image: Depth of fish individuals over time. The background represents the temperature, the grey dots is the raw depth data, and the black line is the geom_smooth line of raw data]

Answer (score 1):

I think specifying the range you want by adding this argument into the ggplot section should solve it

```
+coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 10),ylim = c(10,40))
```

Comment: I added it after the first ggplot call, but got this error:

Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only

Do you know what it means?

Comment: Try putting it after you specify the geom. I'm not sure what the error means but it might be that the argument is incompatible with the geom you're using